# Heartbeat in Harmony pattern with ZeroMQ

Tags: zeromq

I have read a good article about Harmony pattern for ZeroMQ

Here it is for reference http://randalh.blogspot.ie/2012/12/zeromq-true-peer-connectivity-harmony.html

It suggests using DEALER sockets for outcoming data and ROUTER for incoming.

I am considering using this pattern, but one thing is not quite clear for me before implementing this. It is how heartbeats should be done correctly.

Let's say I am doing it via DEALER. If the dealer thinks that no other side is connected (by whatever internal check it is doing) my ping message stucks and send should block if I am understanding the semantics correctly. Should I try to switch to non-blocking mode and not resend ping unless if one is already pending?

If I should do it via ROUTER, then how do I control connectivity via my DEALER connections?

P.S. Also it feels like I am reimplementing something already available at ZeroMQ, e.g. some connectivity checks. Can I reuse it?

Answer (score 1):

Heartbeating lets your application know if there's a successful connection, because ZMQ's knowledge about what sockets are connected or not is unreliable (and so, not even available to you).

As for how to do it, it's very dependent upon your specific circumstances.  In general, it doesn't matter if you get pings to queue up because the peers disconnected, so I'd say just keep sending them.  Whether you use blocking or non-blocking is dependent on your app and your language.  But you probably want to heartbeat from both sides, so long as you control both sides, so ping from both DEALER and ROUTER.

Comment: It feels quite wrong to me that once I have sent the message and didn't get a response from server and I don't know if it was not delivered or it is still in the queue. If I can leave the app for a day disconnected and after a day it will hammer the server with 10000k pings. It is not a large number, but somewhat wasteful. Also if I am processing multiple nodes in one cycle it will block in unpredictable way not because of real pressure, but because of phantom disconnections.

Comment: Is there a way to have just unreliable equal peer N-to-N? I need only buffer handling, separate thread IO and delimiting from ZMQ, not much more

Comment: Short answer: you can probably do what you want, but I don't know enough about your situation to be able to say for certain if or how you would do it.  This feels like it's drifting away from an appropriate question for StackOverflow, you probably need to do more research and try something out, and then come back with a specific problem you can demonstrate with code.